# onCreateOptionsMenu compile error

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I tried to use `onCreateOptionsMenu` in my application. I followed developers blog and it didn't work of me.

When i use this code:

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.homepage_actionbar, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

I got this compile errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected


    - Illegal modifier for parameter onCreateOptionsMenu; only final is 
     permitted

    - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

Multiple markers at this line
    - Void methods cannot return 
     a value
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item 
    android:id="@+id/add_option"
    android:title="Add Item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
 />    
</menu>
```

Thank for helping

Comment: @tyczj i added my xml file

Comment: everything looks fine so error is probably outside of what you posted. did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code that you haven't posted. Your IDE should be telling you where.

Comment: i got some syntex error out of this code, thanks

Comment: Is `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside of a method?

Comment: The error says "Void methods cannot return a value". Is the code your present really a copy/paste of your code ? it says that the method is void but you return a value ?

Comment: Are you sure you defined onCreateOptionsMenu at the right place ? as @codeMagic said, did you put that code inside of a method ? If yes it is wrong it must be directly in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your onCreateOptionsMenu method to be implemented in another method of your Activity.

Just move it at the "root" level of your Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code, that error is probably due to the fact a curly bracket is missing you either `{` or `}` or as @codeMagic said you have your code running in a method which is wrong you must have it directly in the class.